# User Feedback on Crash win forms

Tags: c#, crash-reports

I am making an image editing program. At this point I want to implement a way of getting information from the user about what he was doing when the program crashed. Currently I only manage to e-mail me just the `Exception`. I am creating a second form when the program starts in which I have a `RichTextBox` where I ask the user to explain what he was doing at that moment. When I saw that the e-mail leaves without the explanation and the new form just closes almost instantly I tried creating it on a different thread, still having the same result. I am doing all of these on `UnhandledException` event. To test it I was raising a `new Exception()` right after adding the handler to the event.

Is there a different approach I could use?

```
private void reportCrash(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            ParameterizedThreadStart pth = new ParameterizedThreadStart(reviewForm);
            crash = new Thread(pth);
            crash.Start(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        }

private void reviewForm(object exception)
        {
            Form f = popForm("Feedback/ Bug Report", 500, 700);
            Label name_lb = popLabel(150, 50, "Display name: ", f);
            TextBox name = popText(250, 50, f);
            Label message_lb = popLabel(100, 100, "Please describe what were you doing when the bug occured:", f);
            RichTextBox message = popRichText(100, 130, 300, 400, f);
            Button bt = popButton(200, 550, "Send", f);

            bt.Click += (sender, e) => { sendBug(sender, e, (string)exception); };
        }

private void sendBug(object sender, EventArgs e, string exception)
        {
            string message = "Report sent by:   ";
            message += ((Button)sender).FindForm().Controls[1].Text + "\n\n";
            message += "User's message:\n";
            message += ((Button)sender).FindForm().Controls[3].Text + "\n\n";
            message += "Exception:\n" + exception;

            sendReport(message, "Crash report");

            ((Button)sender).FindForm().Close();
        }
```

All the "pop" methods create the control they specify, I use them quite often in my program.

```
Form popForm(string txt, int w, int h)
        {
            Form f = new Form();
            f.Text = txt;
            f.Size = new Size(w, h);
            f.Show();

            return f;
        }
```

Comment: Hard to guess what popForm() might do.  Well, not what it is supposed to do.  You *must* use ShowDialog() so it can function correctly on a worker thread.

Comment: @HansPassant It creates the new form. I use `f.Show();` at the end in that method. I edited the question. So you say that ShowDialog() is different from Show()?

Comment: That's what I guessed at.  Wrong, you must use ShowDialog().  Show() can only work on a thread that pumps a message loop (aka Application.Run).  ShowDialog() pumps its own loop.  Necessarily that ShowDialog() call must be made at the end of reviewForm().

Comment: @HansPassant Should I scrap the `popForm` method so Show() is no longer called?

Comment: @HansPassant Now, I can see the new form, but the Windows gives me the "Program has stopped running" window and doesn't let me do anything with the form. After that it closes it, but I still get the bug in my e-mail. Is there a way to shut down the main thread so that error doesn't show up but the second thread would still work?

Comment: Don't use a thread at all, there is no point to it.  You want to ensure that your AppDomain.UnhandledException event handler does not return so the OS cannot see the failure.  So your method must block while the report is displayed (it already does thanks to ShowDialog) and must end with Environment.Exit().

Comment: Usually, all UI stuff should be in the main UI thread of a WinForms application. As already mentionned, you should use `ShowDialog` to display a modal form. Finally, why are you using the design to create yours forms?

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the help, everything seems to be working properly now.

Comment: @Phil1970 I am not using the designer, I'm creating all my controls programmatically.

Comment: This is why I recommand you to use the designer as it does not make much sense to create controls programmatically if the layout is static and you are using standard controls that generate not much code bloat. For some complex controls like charts and grids, it could make sense or if the UI is really dynamic...